# how to load many image resource with function

Tags: android, image, resources

i have an public int[] image resource id :

```
public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.im1,R.drawable.im2,R.drawable.im3,R.drawable.im4,R.drawable.im5,R.drawable.im6,R.drawable.im7,R.drawable.im8,R.drawable.im9,R.drawable.im10,R.drawable.im11,R.drawable.im12,R.drawable.im13,R.drawable.im14};
```

i make equivalence for "public static int [] prgmImages" , with "load()" :

```
 int[]    prgmImages  =load(null);





private int[] load (int[] x)
{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
       x[i]= getResources().getIdentifier("im"+i+1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                                  }
return x ;
}
```

but i get an error !!!
where is the problem ?

05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.shahid.varamin/ir.shahid.varamin.list}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at ir.shahid.varamin.list.load(list.java:146)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at ir.shahid.varamin.list.onCreate(list.java:86)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971):    ... 12 more

Comment: _"but i get an error!!!"_ is not valid debugging. You have a stack trace, which you can read in the logcat.

Comment: i want to know , this function is true ???

Comment: I'd suggest that you read up on basic debugging, in general and in Android. You read stack traces, print stuff, attach a debugger etc.

Comment: seriously not getting what you want?

Comment: i dont ask hard question , i want to change public static int [] prgmImages to function load , just ....

Comment: or what is the equivalence of "public static int [] prgmImages" in function ?? i write "load" function , but have problem !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass null to your load method, it's not surprising that you get an error.

Why don't you instantiate your array in the load() method, such as `int[] x = new int[15]`, and make the method parameterless.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This does not answer the original question and might be better as a comment on their question.

Comment: Hossein's question is "I get an error, why?". The stack trace contains "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 05-02 17:17:01.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18971): at ir.shahid.varamin.list.load(list.java:146)", so that it's clear that he is indeed passing a null pointer to the load() method.